# New methods of treatment of psychological trauma?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, methodology, experimental-psychology, trauma

Classical methods of psychological treatment of trauma help many people, but there is always a percentage of the patients those are can’t be healed with classical methods like Drug interventions, Cognitive behavioural psychotherapy, Gestalt therapy, Psychoanalytic therapy, EMDR etc.

Are there any perspective methods for them? For example, might it be possible to erase the effects of psychological trauma as if trauma itself never happened?

Comment: With regard to erasing memory and other effects of trauma, you may find https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16781/7604 or https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21319/7604 helpful.  With CBT for trauma, there is my answer at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/17325/7604

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is post-traumatic stress disorder preventable?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16781/is-post-traumatic-stress-disorder-preventable)

Comment: I suspect that many of the same treatments being investigated [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/23150/7001) could apply to PTSD just as well.